# Android - MediaPlayer starts to play faster by using IP instead of the address. Why?

Tags: android, dns, ip, media-player, rtsp

I am using the mediaPlayer.setDataSource method to set a rtsp streaming. It has the following format:

```
 rtsp://X/vod/" + stringEncoded +"/mp4:" +  music + ".mp4
```

Turns out that when I put the direct IP in X, the music starts playing in about 4 seconds. However, when I put the address, it takes 15 seconds to start playing!

This is not a problem of DNS because it solves the address instantly and I also have an iOS application that uses the same address and it works instantly. This is probably some problem in how Android interprets the IP returned by the DNS.

I can't use the direct IP because I must balance the requests in the DNS (sending each request to a different machine (a different IP)).

Does anybody have any clue why android takes so much longer to start playing a song when I use the address instead of the IP?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the IP using the java InetAddress class and using that IP in the URL. That way it worked. Here is the code:

```
 // Get domain name from URL
 String domainName = new String("my_address_here");

 // Get IP address as string
 InetAddress inet = null;

 try {
       inet = InetAddress.getByName(domainName);
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
       Log.i("[DNS Problem]", "The IP address cannot be resolved for " + domainName);
 }
  String    resolvedIP = inet.getHostAddress();
```

I still have no idea why the setDataSource method messes up with the address though.